# How to round float in multiple of 5

Tags: python, rounding

I got this number `1.12412` and I want to `round it to 1.12415` or `1.12410 (muliple of 5 in last decimal)`

If using the `Round(X,4)` function I get `1.1241 (4 decimals)`.

Is there a function that can make that happen?
Thanks!

There is an answer in stack but using c# not python

Comment: So if the last digit is <= 2 then it shall become 0, when it's  > 2 it shall become 5?

Comment: yes ecxactly. also If there a way to choose if to round up or down?

Answer (score 5):

My way to do that is to specify rounding unit first and then simple trick as below:

```
import numpy as np
rounding_unit = 0.00005
np.round(1.12412/rounding_unit) * rounding_unit
```

Answer (score 0):

You may:

1. Multiply your number by 2
2. Use `Round(X,4)`
3. Divide the result by 2
4. profit!!!